# Efficient substring Search in DynamoDB

Tags: search, substring, amazon-dynamodb

This is the context of my situation:

- I have a huge DB in dynamoDB with 250.000 items. (Example) [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDtYf.png)
- I want to be able to "substring search" through 3 attributes, getting the list of all items that match the substrings.
- The attributes i want to be able to search can have the same value among different items.
- My hash key is an id (the only attribute that really differentiates the items).
- I'm using react native as a client
- My schema has these "query types" [queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiz8F.png)

Where I am:

- I first tried querying with the listCaballos query adding the user input as a filter to the query, and using the nextToken recursively to go over the whole table (without using secondary indexes), but it took 6 minutes to go through the table and return the items.
- I know secondary indexes help to partition and then order the items through chosen keys (which makes it fast), buuuut I read that that forces the user to make an exact search (not a substring kind of search), and that's not what I need.
- I've heard Elastic Search might help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: How large is the table in bytes?

Comment: You basically have to scan the table to get the results.

Comment: Is this an ad hoc query or a new, regular data access pattern?

Comment: @MatthewPope Im not sure what you mean, but I added more info to the question in order to (maybe) answer you.

Comment: @DiegoLeonvendagar Is this a one-time search or something you will need to do frequently? The answer to that question makes a difference to the recommended solution.

Comment: The `contains` function is used for finding matching substrings, but it is not supported for Key Condition Expressions in a query. You could use it as a filter expression in a scan, but if this is a query that happens regularly, then you are better off investing some effort to develop an optimized solution.

Comment: @MatthewPope This query happens regularly and very frequently. I tried scan with filter on a non key attribute and it took 6 minutes to return the items.

Comment: @MatthewPope what do you mean by an optimized solution?

Comment: Well, if you only need to do this infrequently, then an inefficient but simple method like a table scan is okay. Since this query is regular and frequent, then it’s probably worth introducing some complexity in order to make this query quick and efficient.

Comment: @MatthewPope that's precisely what I need, but i'm not familiarized with that "complexity". Do you know what kind of options are there. Do you mean something like Elastic Search or DAX?

Comment: Are there a limited number of substrings that you search for, or is this a completely general string search?

Comment: @MatthewPope I would say completely general string search. For example if the name of one item is 'Jhon' and in another item is 'Jhonas', if I search for 'Jho' I want both items to be returned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not efficient in DynamoDB. Although you can create secondary indexes to search 'begins_with', substring ('contains') capability is there only for filters which are not efficient in a large data set (Since DynamoDB will use IOPS to query all and then apply the filter).

This kind of a requirement, it is efficient to index the database using another service like AWS ElasticSearch or CloudSearch so that you can apply the query on top of that service and configure continuous indexing.

**Getting Started**

- [Searching DynamoDB Data with Amazon CloudSearch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-dynamodb-data.html)
- [Combining DynamoDB and Amazon Elasticsearch with Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/combining-dynamodb-and-amazon-elasticsearch-with-lambda/)
- [Indexing Amazon DynamoDB Content with Amazon Elasticsearch Service Using AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/indexing-amazon-dynamodb-content-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda/)

Answer (score 5):

You will not be able to use secondary indexes to help create a (reasonable) generalized substring search.

There are many ways to solve your problem. Here, I present a few of them, and this is by no means exhaustive.

**DynamoDB -> CloudSearch**

CloudSearch can provide general search functionality for your data. Basically, you can connect a lambda function to the DynamoDB stream from your table. That lambda function can keep your CloudSearch domain up to date. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-dynamodb-data.html) is an overview of this process.

**CloudSearch**

You could forgo DynamoDB and store this data in CloudSearch. That eliminates the need for the lambda function and means your data is only stored in one place. However, you need to tolerate a higher time to consistency because CloudSearch doesn’t have strongly consistent reads like DynamoDB.

**RDS**

You could just use a SQL database of some sort. Most of them support a full text search. You can even use AWS Aurora Serverless if you don’t want to manage database instances.